# How many processes are created in this snippet using fork?

Tags: fork

Can anyone help me in understanding how this will created 19 process?

```
Main()
{
    Fork();
    Fork() && fork () || fork ();
    Fork ();
}
```

Comment: just to clarify, fork() and Fork() means the same function call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to draw a tree of the process creation and study/remember the following points:

P1. `fork()` returns the pid (which is bigger tan 0) to the current process
   and returns 0 in the child process.
 P2. you will need to know how the
   expression `A() && B() || C()` is evaluated; for example if `A()` returns
   `0 (false)` function `B` will not get evaluated because `0 && whatever` is
   always `0`.

Now, let's label the calls to for ease of reference:

```
Main()
{
    Fork() /*[1]*/;
    Fork() /*[2]*/ && fork ()/*[3]*/ || fork ()/*[4]*/;
    Fork ()/*[5]*/;
}
```

I will draw the first level of process creation (and a bit of second level):

```
                          [0]
                /      /     \      \
               [1]    [2]    [3]    [5]

            /  |  \
          [2] [3] [5]
```

The above tree means process [0] (the initial process)  will execute the `fork()` function numbered 1, 2, 3, and 5. Why didn't `process [0]` run `fork()[4]`? Because `fork()[2] && fork[3]` evaluate to true already, so no point to evaluate `fork()[4]`.

Apply similar concept to the process forked by `fork[1]` on the second level to see why process `fork[4]` was not called.

You can complete the process creation tree by applying P1 and P2 at each level of the process creation tree.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that fork has a return value, either 0 or a PID (can't remember if the child gets the PID or the parent). So the && and || operators will evaluate to true when a PID is returned in which case some more processes will be forked. Hope that helps